# AWS Neptune - How Can I Migrate My 1.0.5.1 Based Cluster to Serverless?

Tags: amazon-neptune

**The Problem**

I have an Amazon Neptune cluster with an instance running in `db.t3.medium` DB instnance class. I do not see a choice to move this to the Serverless instance.
[image: The image of Modify Cluster AWS Neptune Setting]

How can I migrate this instance?

Answer (score 1):

**Root Cause**

You can only migrate an instance running Neptune Engine version 1.2 or later.

**How to Fix**

You need to migrate your Neptune Engine version first to 1.2. Once that is done, you will get the migration option to Serverless.

The engine version is controlled not in the cluster instance but at the cluster level and if you are running an older version of the engine, you may need to incrementally upgrade to from the highest version in the major version group, then move up to the next higher version. If you are running 1.0.x, you will first need to go to 1.1.0 R7 then move onto 1.2.

As with any major version upgrade, you could incur some downtime during migration.

To change the engine version, "Modify" the cluster (not instance) settings (the top right button on the console page) and select the latest possible `DB engine version`. You can keep the rest of the settings, and you can apply the change to take effect immediately if you can afford to initiate a downtime shortly after. Continue to upgrade to the next higher level until you reach 1.2. Each upgrade can take a while.

[image]